# Button SaveItem not work

Tags: sql, vb.net, button, tableadapter

I'm trying to build an application that manages a small database, with a TableAdapter. The problem is that the SaveItem button doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
Private Sub PeopleBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PeopleBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.PeopleBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.BankDataSet)
End Sub
```

Thank you to all!

Comment: This has no SQL and the code doesn't look like VBA.  I think the guys looking at VB questions will need a bit more info on what those functions are doing.  What have you tried?  What is the error message?  These are important to troubleshooting.

Comment: Have you made sure the event is firing?  Put a `msgbox("hey")` in there to make sure it is running the subroutine.

Comment: Ok, when i public project, the button works fine..